# Did Loki steal the Tesseract?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

What happened with the Tesseract?

Did Loki steal it at the end of *Thor: Ragnarok*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Did Loki steal it at the end of Thor: Ragnarok?

### I wouldn't necessarily call it stealing, since Odin was already dead and Asgard was about to be destroyed, but yes, it was in Loki's possession.

Towards the end of *Thor: Ragnarok*, both Thor and Loki realize that they need to actually fulfill the Ragnarök prophecy in order to defeat Hela, and to save the Asgardian people.

To accomplish this, Loki was sent to Odin's vault to place Surtur's helm on the Eternal Flame. When walking around down there, Loki notices the Tesseract, but is never shown actually taking it.

[image]

However, in the first few moments of *Avengers: Infinity War*, Loki *is* shown with the Tesseract in possession. IIRC though, when Loki reveals to have the Tesseract, Thor acted surprised, and so, it would seem that Thor didn't know Loki had it.

So, did Loki take the Tesseract at the end of *Thor: Ragnarok*? Yes. But, was it stolen? Depends on if you consider not telling Thor to be stealing or not.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - it's shown in *Avengers: Infinity War* that Loki has it, right up until

> Thanos kills pretty much all the Asgardians and takes it from him.